# Possible to determine if a stream is a string?

Tags: c#, stream

Is it possible to somehow (without a huge performance loss) determine if a Stream (just a normal System.IO.Stream) "contains" a string or not? I have tried to google this, but I havent found a good solution that doesnt involve try and catching.

Comment: @stuartd a stream can only contain binary data

Comment: @stuartd well any binary data could be a string - depending on the encoding

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any stream can be a string as a string is just a series of bytes.  If you're asking if a stream contains a specific sequence of bytes -- i.e. you want to confirm that a stream contains a $*MY_TOKEN*$ somewhere then you'll have to read up until that point or to the end of the stream.

Depending on the nature of your stream, there might be an efficient way to do this and then reset the cursor back to the beginning of the stream.

Comment: You missed the encoding. Without knowing the encoding you can not be sure to get the right string out of the stream